# soundcloud node npm

Tags: node.js, soundcloud

Is there an official or "blessed" Node.js NPM module for interacting with SoundCloud.

There are a few wrapper API's around.  I'm wondering whether there is a favoured one by the community.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is one.

https://github.com/podviaznikov/soundcloud-node

```
npm install soundcloud
```

Comment: Thanks @insurejw.  I looked at that one, and it was a year since last commit, and had noise like `.idea` (IDE hidden files) and `npm-debug.log` checked into it.  Hence why I went looking for one that might have been given more love.

Perhaps it's fine.  Have you had a good experience with it, per chance?  Thanks!

Comment: @PhilCockfield No I haven't used Souldcloud at all. I simply googled it.

Comment: So you weren't sure if this was an official client? That's very misleading.

Answer (score 0):

there is NOT a blessed module for node.js. There is a decent pacakge here: https://github.com/khilnani/soundclouder.js/blob/master/lib/soundclouder.js

It's currently maintained but still pretty basic

Answer (score 0):

I just updated my own Soundcloud NodeJS Api-Wrapper Package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/soundcloud-nodejs-api-wrapper

You can do server side only API communication, which includes data manipulation on the account for the given credentials. No user permission popup window is needed.

So far I did not found any other package for nodejs supporting this.