# Are there any plans to make a server side javascript api for usage with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sdk, soundcloud

There are a number of inconveniences for javascript developers that would want to use soundcloud from the server side. The node wrapper that is not officially supported requires authentication every time, something that is allowed for python and ruby servers.

Is there a plan to provide a node api? If so when would the planned release be?

Comment: This isn't really the right place to be asking a question like this.  I'd suggest you find some discussion forum/group specifically for soundcloud.

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of [soundcloud node npm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13025654/soundcloud-node-npm) and some discussion here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/soundcloudapi/XGN48CHdB58

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question for developers of another organisation. This better be posted on forums of the said organisation.

Comment: @S.D.: What is the correct flag in that case?

Comment: @S.D. I merely posted this here because the SoundCloud documentation directs developers to ask all of their questions by tagging posts on this site with soundcloud. This is therefore not off-topic by their own support guidelines. Believe me when I tell you I know I shouldn't have to ask this on here.